# C# How to Make Enum as a switch?

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, calculator

how use enum values in switch cases ?
here is my code :

```
    //public Variables        
    double rat;
    string M;
    public enum operations {add = 1, sub = 2, mult = 3, div = 4} ;
    bool NewText = false;

    private void btnmult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Button "*"  
        operations value = operations.mult;
        rat = Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);
        label1.Text = rat + " *";
        result.Text = "";
    }
      private void EqualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (operations) // this is the point which is am confused at
        {            
            case (operations.mult): //multiplyication
                TheEqualMult(rat);
                label1.Text = "";
                break;
        }
    }
```

now What i should write after the word switch between the () ? what i want to type is the enum value which refers to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 so the button can know which is right operation to go in.

Comment: `switch (value)`, if `value` contains the value you're interested in. Btw, consider following [.NET naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx). Things like classes, enums, methods are PascalCased in .NET.

Comment: i get in the case (operations.mult) "Windows_Calculator.Form1.operations' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Just a side note: As a rule of thumb enums should be named singular (ie `operation`) unless they can be combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what you are looking for.

Note that when declaring enums, values will be automatically assigned incrementally. By default the first value is zero, unless you override it.

In your switch statement you use the variable whose value you are switching on - in your case value.

```
double rat;
string M;
public enum operations 
{
    add = 1,
    sub,
    mult,
    div
} ;
bool NewText = false;
operations value;

private void btnmult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button "*"  
    value = operations.mult;
    rat = Convert.ToDouble(result.Text);
    label1.Text = rat + " *";
    result.Text = "";
    }

private void EqualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    switch (value) // use a variable at this point
    {            
        case operations.mult: //multiplication
            TheEqualMult(rat);
            label1.Text = "";
            break;
        case operations.add: //addition
            ....
            break;
        case operations.sub: //subtraction
            ....
            break;
        case operations.div: //division
            ....
            break;
        default: //invalid operation
            ....
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that in the above code value will default to zero - effectively an invalid enum - so you need the default at the end.

Comment: i still get a error "Windows_Calculator.Form1.operations' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Where do you get that error - I have tried the code & do not get that error.

Comment: nah i only showed the multiply case as a example i have 3 more operations

Comment: As for your error - are you assigning the enum to an int or vice-versa at somepoint - that would give that error.

Comment: i made public int which is called value in the beginning of the code should i remove it ?

Comment: See my modified code - value needs to be the enum type.

Comment: Thank you so Much . it Worked :D

Answer (score 2):

Your current example method has value hard coded to "Mult" but I assume that would be changed in your actual implementation.

Assuming "value" contains the enumeration value corresponding to the button clicked, your Switch Statement should switch on that variable:

```
switch(value)
```

Comment: what should i right in cases to give the value of operations.mult ?

Comment: That would come from the button it's self - probably in your event args.

Answer (score 0):

Inbetween the parentheses you don't use "operations" (which is a type) but a variable (which you named "value" 5 lines before).
Also in the cases (two lines after the troublesome line) you don't need to use parentheses (they don't do harm except for others you collaborate with)

Comment: i get this error "Windows_Calculator.Form1.operations' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Can you provide some of the code? Note that an Enum is an int at its core, so conversion from Enum to int can be done implicitly, but to go from int to Enum you need to cast explicitly. e.g. 'int i = myEnum.OptionOne' and the inverse 'myEnum x = (myEnum)1' - from the error I would guess the second is occurring.